# git diff for a single file

Tags: git

`git log proto.php` will lists all commits for proto.php

Is there a command which will show me not only commit messages for this file but all diffs for all commits? A kind of complete history of diffs for a single file.

Comment: Should have mentioned, that i normally use Git extensions -> file history.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`git log -p proto.php`

You could have just read the manual, but I'll be happy to take the rep points.

Comment: can't let all that Rep go to Uncle Google after all :D